# Slidify Quiz Answer is of Character Class

Tags: r, slidify

I'm using the package **Slidify** written by Ramnath Vaidyanathan.
I was creating my first **quiz** using the widget [quiz].

```
--- &multitext  

    1. Create a vector x of the length three, which must consist of the following values 2 , 3, and 7.

*** .hint 
Use the command c()

*** .explanation
1. <span class="answer">x<-c(2,3,7)</span>
```

This all is fine, but in the text-input area, if you type x<-c(2,3,7) as an answer you get incorrect icon. Is it working only with numeric class? Is it possible to implement the character class into quiz?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this widget is only setup to only accept numeric answers. It is easy to enable character input, but I believe it would be unreliable. For example, a user can type different answers, character-wise and they would all be correct.

```
x <- c(2,  3, 7)
x<-c(2,3,7)
x<-c(2,3,  7)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it can be very helpful for me. Because the quiz I'm creating has for example questions, where you just have to type in the name of the function like `lm` or `plot` or `summary`. How can I enable character input? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This would require changes to the javascript library underlying the quiz. Especially [these lines](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyLibraries/blob/master/inst/libraries/widgets/quiz/js/jquery.quiz.js#L361-L370). I will think what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Any idea how to modify these lines making them character friendly.